# Run non admin script from admin script

Tags: scripting

i have a script :

```
param(
    [string]$UserEmail
)

Write-Host "Received UserEmail parameter: $UserEmail"

# Define parameters
$SiteID = "$SiteID"
$WebID = "$WebID"
$WebURL =[System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlEncode("https://mysharepoint")
$ListID = "$ListID"
$WebTitle = "SP"
$ListTitle = "Documents"

# Construct the odopen URL
$odopen = "odopen://sync/?siteId=$SiteID&webId=$WebID&webUrl=$WebURL&listId=$ListID&userEmail=$UserEmail&webTitle=$WebTitle&listTitle=$ListTitle"

# Start the sync
Start-Process $odopen
```

so this script works fine in non admin and im needed to run in non admin (obviosuly i add the &UserEmail manualy when i test

Now I have another who doing many thing so i need to run in admin

```
function Sync-SharePointLibrary {
    param(
        [string]$EmailToSync
    )

    # The path to your second script
    $PS1FilePath = "$driveLetter\Config PC\SyncSP.ps1"

    # Check if the script exists
    if (!(Test-Path $PS1FilePath)) {
        throw "Specified PowerShell script not found"
    }

    # Run the PowerShell script with the desired arguments, without admin privileges
   Start-Process "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-NoExit -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $PS1FilePath -UserEmail $EmailToSync"



    Write-Output "Second script started successfully."
}
```

everytime the first sript open and close directly , no error nothing , i already try to add some debug and logs file but non are created already try to create a bat from the script to satrt the second script not working

if i run the script with admin i got my error that i need to be regular user to run so im almost certain that my probleme is to run in non admin from admin ps

please any idea ?

Thanks

, no error nothing , i already try to add some debug and logs file but non are created already try to create a bat from the script to satrt the second script not working